# Looking for a study

Tags: life-of-jesus, archaeology

I was reading and came across an article stating:

> A recent archaeological expedition to Israel uncovered scrolls that
>   appear to depict the story of Jesus’ crucifixion. On one of the
>   scrolls is a sketch that shows a man, thought to be Jesus, smoking
>   from a pipe. Below the drawing is the Hebrew word “kineboisin”, which
>   translates to cannabis.
>
> Dr. Isaac Cohen, president of the South Israel Archaeological Society,
>   believes that this is an extremely significant discovery for the
>   theological community.

I am looking for the original study and cannot find it. I cannot even find a South Israel Archaeological Society nor can I find a Dr. Isaac Cohen. I only find references to this little blurb that I posted here. I am not here looking for a debate on whether this is true or false I am looking only to see if others know where I can find this original study or information on this to backup these claims.

If this is considered off-topic or offensive to some I apologize.

Thanks for any help ion tracking this information down.

Comment: where did you find the article you quote from?

Comment: It's old, but we recently started allowing these things: [Should we accept "Help me find this thing" questions?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3766) and [Are we now allowing "shopping questions"?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3952)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Christian beliefs. I suggest asking on History.SE.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Considering that the only references to this text are on websites attempting to campaign for the legalization of marijuana, I would say that this particular person and institution are complete fabrications.

Wikipedia has no reference for this particular Archaeological society. On the other hand there was a prominent Jewish Rabbi named [Dr. Isaac Cohen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Cohen), but he was the chief Rabbi of Ireland not an archaeologist .

These facts seem to continue the confirmation that this story is a complete fabrication to attempt to show some evidence of cannabis use in the life of Christ.

Comment: To be honest here I am for the legalization of marijuana. With that said I hate when people make up stories as it end up hurting the cause vs helping. Thanks for the help =>

Comment: @Looking as Caleb suggested, submitting this to snopes would be a great idea.

Comment: I Agree and believe I will do just that

Answer (score 12):

Quite honestly I think you should submit this to [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/). Every single last references to such an organization are found on websites of people trying to promote the legalization of marijuana, and they all follow almost the same format. No further linking is every provided and the wording is always the same. It sounds like an hoax that somebody made up and threw out there for humor and then folks took it and ran with it until it became a legend.

Comment: Why not skeptics.SE, while you're about it?

Answer (score -1):

Link: http://www.freeanointing.org/The_Fire_Baptism_Continued.htm
"Are you unwilling to be anointed with the Oil of God? Wherefore we are called Christians on this account, because we are anointed with the oil of God." Theophilus of Antioch (181AD)

After water baptism, " We are thoroughly anointed with a blessed unction, (a practice derived), from the old discipline, wherein on entering the priesthood, then were wont to be anointed with oil from a horn, ever since Aaron was anointed by Moses. Whence Aaron is called "Christ." Tertullian of Carthage "On Baptism."(160 - 225 AD)
Link: Found! The Holy Anointing Oil Container of James the Just and the Apostles.http://www.freeanointing.org/freechristian.htm
"The ancient Aramaic is transliterated as, "La Shemen Ruehon" (For the Oil of the Spirit)"
And your yoke shall be removed because of the anointing oil" Isaiah 10:27

Etymology (from Wikipedia): 
The word cannabis is from Greek κάνναβις (kánnabis) (see Latin cannabis),[4] which was originally Scythian or Thracian.[5] It is related to the Persian kanab, the English canvas and possibly even to the English hemp (Old English hænep).[5] In modern Hebrew, קַנַּבּוֹס qannabōs modern pronunciation: [kanaˈbos] is used but מַעֲלֶה עָשָׁן maʿăleh ʿāšān modern pronunciation: [ma.aˈle aˈʃan] (smoke bringer) is the ancient term. Old Akkadian qunnabtu, Neo-Assyrian and Neo-Babylonian qunnabu were used to refer to the plant meaning "a way to produce smoke."[6][7][8]

Ancient Israel: Sula Benet ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sula_Benet ) (in 1967) claimed that the plant kaneh bosm קְנֵה-בֹשֶׂם mentioned five times in the Hebrew Bible is cannabis,[35] although most dictionaries of plants of the Bible typically identify the plant in question as either Acorus calamus or Cymbopogon citratus.[36]

It is also interesting to note that the Darby Bible makes a number of reference to "fragrant drugs"

Answer (score -1):

I saw the original article that had a picture of the page with the supposed Jesus and his pipe and the words at the bottom. I should have saved it a few years ago when I found it but I didn't. Weather it was true or not. Sula Bennett in 1936 in Warsaw Poland searched the word Cannabis back to 5 places in the Old Testament including Exodus 30:23. The holy anointing oil. William Randolph Hurst helped criminalize Cannabis under the name marijuana in 1937 when he wrote in his newspapers that black and Mexican men were smoking it and raping white women. That's all it took. William Randolph Hurst also is responsible for fluffing Billy Graham. A 33rd degree mason. The beginning of the Faith without works Gospel that Satan loves.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What follows next has ***nothing*** to do with the quality of your answer (which is good); it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first). As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites). I hope to see you around!

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE! When you get a second, check out a bit of [who we are]( http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1381/4188) and what makes us different than other sites (Aaron's link above); we're not a discussion forum but an academically minded Q&A; you have some interesting facts, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the referenced story above is fabricated. The original study cannot be found anywhere and it looks like the South Israel Archaeological Society does not even exist for if it did one would be able to find it on the net. Same thing goes for the elusive Dr. Isaac Cohen, who and where are they in this world. No one has pin pointed that person neither.

However, with that all said... Humans and animals were "created" with an endocannabionoid system (CB1 and CB2 receptors, which are expressed predominantly in the brain and immune system) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endocannabinoid_system and the ONLY created item or plant that interacts and binds with the endocannabinoid system and receptors like a key to a lock is cannabis.

We have seen and heard many studies and reports that cannabis helps with epilepsy even in children (CBD) and how cannabis has even helped many with cancer, pain management, MS, PTSD and so many other horrible diseases in which western medicine and the pharmaceuticals want to administer synthetic drugs that cost a lot but do not work as efficiently or at all and at the same time they maintain complete control over these synthetic drugs which often time are harmful and even lethal through the FDA.

If one does some true historical research on Cannabis you will be shocked at what you find out.

I am a Christian who loves Jesus Christ immensely. I know that our body is a temple of the Holy Spirit within us, whom we have from God? So we are to glorify God in our body.

I know that scripture also states that we should not be conformed to this world, but be transformed by the renewal of your mind, that by testing you may discern what is the will of God, what is good and acceptable and perfect.

We are to be sober-minded and watchful and that the devil prowls around like a roaring lion, seeking someone to devour and that we are not to get drunk with wine, for that is debauchery, but be filled with the Spirit,

We know that satan is the great justifier. He always wants to help us rationalize and justify sinning against God, almost making it seem like the right thing to do.

So the questions as Christians is... since GOD the creator of Heaven and earth created us with an endocannabinoid system in which the ONLY creation on this planet that binds to the endocannabinoid receptors and fits like a key to a lock is Cannabis, then the only conclusion is that God made this plant as medicine for us to use.

I don't believe people should lose their senses by getting "stoned or wasted", however for proper use and health reasons cannabis should be legal. Every day there are more and more people and studies showing that this plant has the capability to help or even save ones life in situations where synthetic drugs have failed.

God created all things and I know He certainly did not make a mistake when He created the endocannbioid system and I believe we will see more and more miraculous studies as to how beneficial this plant truly is in the coming years.

God Bless <><

Comment: Welcome to the site. For future reference please see [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809) I hope to see you post again soon.